# UnsatisfiedLinkError at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I am using `scanlibrary` module  in my project and it works fine, but when I include `tess-two 6.0.4` in  `build.gradle` file it generates following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime
>
> nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.scanner.demo-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.scanner.demo-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"

When I comment out `compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.4'` from the build.gradle file, app works fine again.

Is it a compatibility issue or I am doing something wrong.

**My Project Structure:**

[image]

Comment: After wasting a day i finally solved it. The "arm64-v8a" file generated by open-cv library is not present in tess-two library. So i used this in my app build.gradle file to exclude the particular folder.           

abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"

Answer (score 3):

I used "abiFilters" in app's build.gradle file to solve the issue.

`defaultConfig{
    ********
    ndk{
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }
}`

If your project structure look different you might also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030900/android-unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-tesseract-and-opencv)

Comment: Nice solution. The problem is that the shared object files for 64-bit ABIs (arm64-v8a, mips64, x86_64) are present in tess-two, but absent in scanlibrary. This solution successfully works around the problem by filtering to only use the specified ABIs.